# How to sort table with uuid value

Tags: mysql, activiti

We are using activity **5.18** in our project and I need to clean up `ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY` in our prod env.

The schema is,

```
CREATE TABLE "ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY" (
  "ID_" varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  "REV_" int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  "NAME_" varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  "DEPLOYMENT_ID_" varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  "BYTES_" longblob,
  "GENERATED_" tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("ID_"),
  KEY "ACT_FK_BYTEARR_DEPL" ("DEPLOYMENT_ID_"),
  CONSTRAINT "ACT_FK_BYTEARR_DEPL" FOREIGN KEY ("DEPLOYMENT_ID_") REFERENCES "ACT_RE_DEPLOYMENT" ("ID_")
);
DEPLOYMENT_ID_ and GENERATED_ column are null by default.
```

The problem here is id_ column type is uuid and sorting by id_ column is not really useful.

How to sort and find the older data, possibly a year old data to purge.

Comment: Why can't you use order by `DateTime`?

Comment: I don't have field which contains DateTime. Can explain more specific way?

Comment: So how do you know whether row is older than a year?

Comment: @Tajniak Thats the question i have asked?

Comment: Let's move your problem to the side. How do you know if row with ID=1 is older than year? How can you check this?

Comment: I have achieved this by using  this script.. "delete from ACT_GE_BYTEARRAY where id_ in (select bytearray_id_ from ACT_HI_VARINST where bytearray_id_ is not null and CREATE_TIME_ < date_sub(current_Date(), interval 360 day));"